# reduce Observable<Observable<T>> to Observable<T>

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to get a list of `EventShift`s from the database on the background using RxJava scheduler like this :

```
Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Observable<EventShift>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<EventShift> call() throws Exception {
                return Observable.from(shiftDb.getAll());
            }
        })
```

EDIT : just to clearify i want to act upon each of the `EventShift` objects using flatMap later, so i need `Observable<EventShift>`...

As i am pretty new to RxJava, First question would be - is there a better way to do that to avoid the `Observable<Observable<>>`?

And even if there is a better approach, how can i reduce `Observable<Observable<>>` to `Observable<>`?

Comment: The inner observable from isn't needed: `Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<EventShift>...`

Comment: Retourn shiftdb.getall directly, instead of Observable.from. Update your anonymous class signature (or it won't compile)

Comment: @zapl but then i would get Observable<List<EventShift>> while i want Observable<EventShift>

Comment: What is a problem with just Observable.from(shiftDb.getAll()) ?

Comment: @yurgis that shiftDb.getAll() will be executed in the same thread rather than on a scheduler in the background.  shiftDb.getAll() might take time to execute

Comment: Have you tried flatmap?

Comment: @DanielK you can see what i did in my answer, you are more than welcome to offer another approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing :

```
Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<List<EventShift>>() {
            @Override
            public List<EventShift> call() throws Exception {
                return shiftDb.getAll();
            }
        }).flatMap(new Func1<List<EventShift>, Observable<EventShift>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<EventShift> call(List<EventShift> eventShifts) {
                return Observable.from(eventShifts);
            }
        }).map(new Func1<EventShift, ...>() {
            @Override
            public ... call(EventShift eventShift) {
                //...
            }
        })
```

if any 1 can suggest a better or just diffrent approach please do...

Comment: the only thing you can do "better" is to use [retro lambda](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrolambda/article.html) which turns the ugly looking multi-line flatMap call into a simple `.flatMap(eventShifts -> Observable.from(eventShifts))`

Answer (score 1):

You want the canonical method, which is `defer`:

```
Observable<List<EventShift>> obs = Observable.defer(() -> shiftDb.getAll());
```

`defer` will call that lambda/method/Func0 each time the Observable gets subscribed to.